# A map between tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove the next fact.

> Suppose $V, V', W, W'$ are vector spaces over a field F. Let $\phi: V\otimes V' \rightarrow W \otimes W'$ be a linear map. Prove that if $V'$ and $W'$ are finite-dimensional, then there exists maps $\phi_1^{i}:V\rightarrow W$ and $\phi_2^{i}: V'\rightarrow W'$ such that $\phi = \sum_i\phi_1^{i}\otimes \phi_2^{i}$.

I am trying the following definitions for the maps. Fix some basis $v_1, \ldots, v_m$ and $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ of $V'$ and $W'$, then we have maps $\phi_{i, j}:V\rightarrow W \otimes F$ given by  $\phi_{i,j}(x) = (id\otimes w_j^*)\phi(x\otimes v_i)$, where $id:V\rightarrow V$ is the identity map. Also, fix the maps $\phi'_{i, j}:V'\rightarrow W'$ such that $\phi'_{i, j}(v_i)=w_j$ and zero for the rest of the basis elements.

Now, I try to prove $\phi \simeq \sum_i\sum_j\phi_{i,j}\otimes \phi'_{i,j}$. Then for $x, y \in V, V'$, we have
$$\sum_i\sum_j\phi_{i,j}(x)\otimes \phi'_{i,j}(y)= \sum_i\sum_j(id\otimes w_j^*)\phi(x\otimes v_i)\otimes v_i^*(y)w_j=\sum_j(id\otimes w_j^*)\phi(x\otimes y)\otimes w_j.$$

My intuition tells me we have $\sum_j(id\otimes w_j^*)\phi(x\otimes y)\otimes w_j = \phi(x, y) \otimes 1$, but I am not sure why.

Any hint?